# How to display category from recent posts?

Tags: posts, categories

I have a code for display recent posts:

`<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<h2><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </h2> ';
        echo '<p>' . date_i18n('d F Y', strtotime($recent['post_date'])) .'</p> ';
        // what code here?
    }
    wp_reset_query();
?>`

now I want to display category name and link also. What kind of code should I use in here? I try some but without effect...

Thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_the_category_list()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category_list) to output a comma-separated list of links to categories:

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<h2><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </h2> ';
        echo '<p>' . date_i18n('d F Y', strtotime($recent['post_date'])) .'</p> ';
        echo get_the_category_list( ', ', '', $recent["ID"] );
    }
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Ok, but it's shows only one category, independently of post :/

Comment: Sorry, I left out passing the post ID to the function. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

i know This is the different code but works as you want hope so,you can try

```
<?php
    $myposts = array( 'post_type' => 'post','posts_per_page' => 5); 
    $all_post = new WP_Query($myposts);
    if ( $all_post->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $all_post->have_posts() ) :
            $all_post->the_post();

            echo get_the_title();
            echo '<p>' . 'Category Name:' . get_the_category_list($post->ID ) . '</p>';
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```